# Bold text cut off in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab R2014a and have discovered that for some plots any bold text size 16 or larger (produced either with the text or title functions) always has the end cut off, no matter how long it is. So even a title like title('Simple Correlation','FontSize',16,'FontWeight','bold') appears as Simple Correlati but reducing the FontSize to 14 makes everything fine, but it's no longer looks bolded. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the results for 1) Resizing the window 2) Change the font 3) adding the title manually?

Comment: Changing the font works! Resizing the window or adding the title manually didn't seem to have any effect. Not sure what was going on with Helvetica but looks like I'll be using Arial for a while. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the font is a workaround, rather than a solution. Please post a minimal code example reproducing your problem and a screenshot.

Comment: The problem only appears for certain functions, i.e. for contourfm but not plot

Comment: The problem appears for me in the following example (data is a 3x1 cell with matrix values):                                  contourfm(data{1},data{2},data{3});                                                title('Simple Correlation','FontSize',16,'FontWeight','bold')

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, switching to Arial from Helvetica solves the problem.